# Как избавиться от "звёздочек", "узелков" у GPS-трека

Tags: php, gps, фильтрация

Есть сырые данные трека, снятого с мобильного тел. У каждой точки есть широта, долгота, временная метка и точность. Надо привязать трек к дороге. Попробовал отфильтровать трек при помощи библиотеки [geojson-tidy](https://github.com/mapbox/geojson-tidy) а затем при момощи Map matching от Mapbox привязал его к дороге. Получилось вот так: [image: geojson-tidy + map matching] синим цветом - трек после фильтрации от geojson-tidy, красный - это привязанный к дороге трек. И всё вроде хорошо, но на месте "звёзд" появляется езда туда-сюда и на месте всплесков появляются фантомные петли. Затем вычитал, что алгоритм Дугласа-пекера может помочь убрать эти звёзы. Заюзал [RDP](https://github.com/david-r-edgar/RDP-PHP), закинул туда сырые координаты трека и коэффициент 0.0005 получилось вот так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения] звезда стала меньше, но не исчезла. Да и всплески особо никуда не делись. Если увеличивать коэффициент, (например до 0.001) то звезда становится ещё меньше, но качество трека заметно падает [image: введите сюда описание изображения], опять-таки всплески никуда не делись. Подскажите пожалуйста инструмент/алгоритм, чтобы убрать все эти звёзды и всплески. Эту задачу же наверняка уже кто то успешно решал?!

Comment: В данных с координатами есть и время? Если есть, то можно рассчитать скорость между соседними точками, если скорость нереальная (при скачках), то игнорировать данную точку. Так получиться избавиться от "скачков", а вмести с ними и с "звездами"

Comment: Попробовал фильтрацию по скорости - не помогло. Отсёк все точки скорость между которыми больше 25 м/с или меньше 0,5 м/с. Звёзды - остались. Такое ощущение, что координата плавно уплывает, а потом возвращается обратно. Видимо как то на ускорение надо завязываться.